# LZH Compression Libraries

Tags: lzh

I'm looking for a LHarc de/compressing library, with source if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few a while back

PASCAL source code (never looked at the validity of it)
http://www.bsdg.org/SWAG/ARCHIVES/0040.PAS.html

Java Version
http://homepage1.nifty.com/dangan/en/Content/Program/Java/jLHA/jLHA.html

Unix version with source
http://sourceforge.jp/projects/lha/